# A reusable CRUD view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, crud

Is it possible to create a set of views that will allow creation updating deleting an viewing any Model ?

In each ViewModel we already place data annotation and validation attributes and so on.. seems that it is not that far away to create a view that by reflection could go thought the Model Type get all the information an create a form.

Dose anything like that exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using an editor template:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

And to have the editor template descend recursively into your complex view model properties you could write a custom editor template for the Object type as Brad Wilson explains in [`this blog post`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) (look at the `Shallow Dive vs. Deep Dive` section towards the end of the article which covers this).

Comment: Thnx... is it good practice to try and create a reusable CRUD view ?

Comment: It all depends on what are your specific project requirements and what you are trying to achieve.